# Loading an attribute on a catalog/product object

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1, certification

I've started working through some practice material for the Magento Certified Developer exam, and one of the questions that I ran into, and that I am still not sure about (I'm struggling to find material about this specific subject) is this:

```
For an attribute to be loaded on a catalog/product object, which two of the following conditions
must be satisfied? (Choose two)

A. The eav_attribute table must contain a row defining the attribute's properties and its entity type.
B. The attribute must have a backend model configured in the XML config.
C. The attribute must be part of the attribute set pertaining to the object being loaded.
D. There must be a record of the attribute on the catalog_product_super_atti:ibute table.
E. There must be a column added to the catalog_product_entity table.
```

**My answers are A and C, is this right? If not, what *is* right, and *why*?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right answers are indeed A and C.

- B is wrong because **an attribute does not necessarily have a backend model configured in the XML configuration.**
- D is wrong because **the `catalog_product_super_attribute` table is only related to the configurable products attributes.**
- E is wrong because **the EAV system does not add extra columns to flat tables, it adds rows to the EAV tables to handle attributes relations.**

Comment: Thanks Raphael! I am trying to study for the exam, I have already found some very informative posts on here for study material - do you have anything specific you would suggest I look at? ( I will mark your answer as accepted as soon as it lets me)

Comment: @Skytiger well apart from the study guide provided on the official magento website I don't have anything else to suggest, it covers all of it